# How can I fix my python word descrambler?

Tags: python

QUESTION: Complete the function scramble(str1, str2) that returns true if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise returns false.

Notes:

Only lower case letters will be used (a-z). No punctuation or digits will be included.
Performance needs to be considered

```
MY CODE:
s1 = 'rkqodlw'
s2 = 'world'

def scramble(s1, s2):
    unscrambled_word = []
    n = 0
    x = 0
    s1_list = list(s1)
    s2_list = list(s2)
    s1_letter = s1_list[n]
    s2_letter = s2_list[x]
    for letters in range(len(s2_list)):
        while n > len(s1_list):
            if s1_letter == s2_letter:
                n = n + 1
                x = x + 1
            else:
                n = n + 1
    return 'True' if x == len(s2_list) else 'False'
```

I am trying to get my code to dissect each of the two strings. If the word of the first string does not match the word of the second string then n will +1 and move onto the second letter. If it matches then both n and x will + 1. My thought on my code is if x == the length of the second string before the giant loop ends then it will return True. Otherwise False. The problem is with the loop. The loop only seems to run through the first two letters of both strings and then stops. I am a fairly new coder any input is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected return? Are you trying to return `True` if s1 is a scrambled version of s2, possibly with extra letters? If so, sets seem like an elegant solution.

Comment: I thought of sets too However sets wont work. If the first word is `moon` and second word is `money`, it will result in True whcih is wrong. When you try to see if word1 is in word2

Comment: Your general idea seems to be right. You got something wrong on your while loop though, you're checking if `n` is bigger than the length of your list, and since `n`  starts at 0, your while loop will never be executed.

Comment: You need to sort both words. Then compare by position. If it does not match then fail

Comment: I am not even sure what sets are yet, like I said I am still am fairly new. But my thought is I don't need to unscramble the words as long as I can get the program to verify that there is enough words in the first string that match words in the second string to create the second string word. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @JoeFerndz that won't work. Imagine if str2="apple" and str1="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaapple". The correct answer is true, but a sorted compare by position would not be equal.

Comment: Agreed. The positioning is important

Comment: Updated code posted. Comparing counts of each letter in s1 and s2 while iterating through set(s2). If the counts are good, then True else False.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure the letters in str2 are all present in str1 in sufficient quantities

```py
def scramble(str1,str2):
    d1 = {}
    for c in str1:
        if not c in d1:
           d1[c] = 0
        d1[c] += 1
    for c in str2:
        if not c in d1 or d1[c] < 1:
            return False
        d1[c] -= 1
    return True
```

The ideas is to go through all the characters in str2 and if for example, str2 has three "a" letters, make sure that str1 has at least three "a" letters. This requires counting the number of times each character occurs in str1. This is most naturally done with a dictionary. A dictionary maps things, called keys, to other things, called values. In this case we map keys which are single characters to a values which are numeric counts.

First step is to create an empty dictionary `d1={}`.
Next is to go character by character in str1 which is the first for loop. For each of these characters, we ask if this character has ever been previously placed into d1. If it has not, then we create a new mapping within d1 for that character to a starting value of zero. Every time a character is encountered in this loop through str1, the count value mapped from that character in d1 is incremented by 1. After the first for loop (that goes through str1) is complete, the dictionary contains counts of every letter in str1.

The next idea is to iterate through every character in str2. If it is a character not present in d1, then that means the character was not present in str1, so str1 is missing a character it would need to scramble into str2. At that point, you can stop processing and just return False.

Otherwise, if you only encounter characters that exist as keys in d1, you subtract one from the d1 mapped count value every time you encounter that character while for looping through str2. If the subtraction would ever cause the d1 count value to go below zero, then that means str2 has a higher number of that particular character than str1 had, so once again str1 cannot scramble into str2. Therefore you can return False at that point and stop processing.

Finally, if we make it through the entire 2nd loop (through str2) without encountering either of the return False cases mentioned above, that means that str1 has at least as many of every character that str2 has and can therefore scramble into str2 using some of its letters. You then return True.

Comment: i am a bit confused on what the computer is doing in some of your code. Do you mind breaking it down a little more and explaining what your code is doing? Sorry I am big newbie lol.

Comment: @Jace I'll add more explanation

Comment: thumb up for the details. Performance-wise I don;t see anything can beat your answer

Comment: @BingWang I liked your use of collections actually. Yours were elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
s1 = 'rkqodlw'
s2 = 'world'

def scramble(s, t):
    d=defaultdict(int)
    for c in s:
        d[c]+=1
    for c in t:
        d[c]-=1
    return min(d.values())>=0
scramble(s1,s2)
```

alternatively use Counter

```
from collections import Counter
s1 = 'rkqodlw'
s2 = 'world'

def scramble(s, t):
    c=Counter(s)
    c.subtract(Counter(t))
    return min(c.values())>=0
scramble(s1,s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
s1 = 'rkqodlw'
s2 = 'world'

def scramble(s1, s2):
  s1_list = list(s1)
  for char in s2:
    if char in s1_list:
      s1_list.pop(s1_list.index(char))
    else:
      return False
  return True

print(scramble(s1,s2))
```

Here's how it works: You run through the loop for each letter in s2, and if that letter is also in a list version of s1, you delete it from that list version. That way, if s2 was `'rabbit'` for example, and s1 was `'braintrain'`, you would meet the first `'r'`, `'a'`, and the first `'b'`, delete it from `'braintrain'` to get `'intrain'`, and the next `'b'`would then fail the test and a `False` would be returned. If there were enough `'b'`s though, the scrambler would return `True`. The final `True`is returned if the test is never failed (that is, all letters in s2 are also in s1) when the function finishes.

Comment: You can use remove as well as you have char already

Comment: I would not recommend this. list pop is O(N) and your answer is O(N^2) complexity. Both Matt and my answer run at O(N)

Answer (score -1):

Updated version:

s1 = scrambled word that may contain s2

s2 = word to be searched

Step 1. Find the set of s2

Step 2. Iterate through each letter of set of s2. Let's call each letter as s

Step 3. For each letter s, find out how many times it occurs in s1 and s2

Step 4: If letter count in s2 <= letter count in s1, then OK, else exit and return False

Step 5: If all letters in set of s2 meet the condition of Step 4, then s2 is in s1. You can return True

The code for this is:

```
def scramble_check(s1,s2):
    return True if all(s2.count(s) <= s1.count(s) for s in set(s2)) else False

print (scramble_check('rkqodlw', 'world'))
print (scramble_check('moonshine', 'moon'))
print (scramble_check('strain', 'brain'))
print (scramble_check('aaaappppleeeset', 'apple'))
print (scramble_check('braintrain', 'rabbit'))
```

Output of the above code is:

```
True
True
False
True
False
```

Jace, to make you understand that one line of code, I expanded the function. Here's the more expanded version.

```
def scramble_check(s1,s2):
    ss = set(s2)  #create a set from word s2
    
    for s in ss: #iterate through each letter in set ss

        #compare count of occurrences of s in both s1 and s2
        #if s2 count is more than s1, then the word cannot be made with s1
        #so return False and exit the function
        if s2.count(s) > s1.count(s): return False

    #if we iterated through all of ss and each letter met the condition, then s2 can be created using s1. So return True
    return True
```

All this is a single line:

```
return True if all(s2.count(s) <= s1.count(s) for s in set(s2)) else
```

Comment: yeah that'll do it - I always forget that str.count function exists. You can probably just directly return all(...) instead of doing the conditional.